# Guzzle3 send raw Post request

Tags: php, guzzle

I am working on project that uses Guzzle3 (v3.9.3), I would like to know how to send a raw post request, I have tried these solutions but none of them worked for me. I am using this Guzzle3 [manual](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/request.html?highlight=raw#raw-post-data).

Solution  :

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('headers', array(
'Authorization' =>  'Bearer '.$token,
'Accept' => 'application/json'
));

$body = '{"filter_":{"user":{"email":"aaa@test.com"}}}';
$req = $client->post($url, array(), $body,
array(
 'cert' => array($certification, 'password'),
)
);
$response = json_decode($client->send($req)->getBody(true));
```

Solution 2 :

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('headers', array(
 'Authorization' =>  'Bearer '.$token,
'Accept' => 'application/json'
));

$body = '{"filter_":{"user":{"email":"aaa@test.com"}}}';

$req = $client->post($url, array(), array(),
 array(
    'cert' => array($certification, 'password'),
 )
);

$req->setBody($body);
$response = json_decode($client->send($req)->getBody(true));
```

None of them worked for me,

Error : Client error response [status code] 404 [reason phrase] Not Found [url]

I have tried some solutions found in the internet (but for Guzzle6) it works but I don't get the right results (it doesn't take in consideration the filter that I have sent , which is the mail address, so I get all results)

```
...
$body = array(
'filter_' => array(
   'user' => array( "email" => $email )
 )
);

$req = $client->post($url, array(),array('body'=> $body),
array(
    'cert' => array($certification, 'password'),
)
);
...
```

On postman the call to WS work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you are limited to Guzzle3? Can you give more information about how you configured the Postman request? (If it can be done in Postman, it can be done in Guzzle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the response in case someone need , I had to put all the bloc between try catch

```
try{
$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('headers', array(
'Authorization' =>  'Bearer '.$token,
));
$body = '{"filter_":{"user":{"email":"aaa@test.com"}}}';
$req = $client->post($url, array(), $body,
array(
 'cert' => array($certification, 'password'),
)
);
$response = json_decode($client->send($req)->getBody(true)); 
catch(Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e){
        $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody(),true);
}
```

Comment: You say, that capturing an exception and decoding it as it was a proper data is a solution?

Comment: when the WS returns empty response I get error that I have mentionned , when I added the bloc catch with BadResponseException and I debug $e I saw that I get the empty response !!